# Is there any short cut/short way to create style resource from xaml code?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have a TextBlock with inline style codes like below.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Txtinfo1"
                       FontSize="30"
                       Padding="35"
                       Foreground="Crimson"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontFamily="Segoe Script"
                       TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       CharacterSpacing="20"
                       Text="Select a New File">
</TextBlock>
```

But I want to create a style resource like below, FROM above code.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="somekey"> ..... </Style>
```

I know how to create a style resource like above manually. My concern is, I want to know whether there is any short way to create style resource by right-clicking already created inline style codes?

Comment: I did not understand what you're saying. Did you want to apply the same one style to   many different TextBlock control?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, I've rephrased my question.

Comment: No. There's no short way to create style.